# How to analyze server crash dump after recent patch update?

Tags: windows, patching

I want to know, if there a way I can identify on windows systems an event / log  generated  due to patches incorrectly installed / or corrupted in the process. Is there a way I can process or look into these logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking for how to do crash dump analysis for determining the source of crash. There are number of techniques though i describe the basic one.

1. First you need to install Windows Debugger (WinDbg.exe) which is installed with windows software development kit.
2. Second part is to configure WinDbg with Microsoft symbol server.